# How to add a <select> <option> with jquery dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Changed value of `<select>` on success response from API with:

```
jQuery('#vat').val(response);
```

With this returned value can be placed into a `textbox`, but need to change the selected value of a `combobox`.

How to realize this?

Here is jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
  function getVat() { // Do an Ajax request to retrieve the product price 
    console.log("getVat before ajax", jQuery('#product_name').val());
    jQuery.ajax({ 
      url: './get/vat/get1.php', 
      method: 'POST', 
      data: {'id' : jQuery('#product_name').val()},
      success: function(response){ 
        console.log("getPrice after ajax", jQuery('#product_name').val());
        jQuery('#vat').val(response);
      }, 
      error: function (request, status, error) { 
        alert(request.responseText); 
      }, 
    });                 
  } 
</script>
```

The script works when `#vat` is a `textbox` but not when `#vat` is a `combobox`.

**Update:**
Here is the script been using for the combobox:

```
<?php
  $dbname = 'db';
  $dbuser = 'root';
  $dbpass = 'pass';

  $db = new mysqli('localhost', $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
  if (!$db) {
    exit('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
    . mysqli_connect_error());
  } 
?>

<select style="width:100%" id="vat" name="vat">
  <option value = "0">No VAT</option>
  <?php
    $queryusers = "SELECT id, internal_id, name FROM vat";
    $db = mysqli_query($db, $queryusers);
    while ( $d=mysqli_fetch_assoc($db)) {
      echo "<option value='".$d['id']."'>".$d['internal_id']." | ".$d['name']."</option>";
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

**Update 2:**

The selected value is changed to '1'. But the script still shows `<option value = "0">No VAT</option>`. Does someone know how I can update the data that is shown.

**Update 3:**

I just get a extra option when I run the following script. The value that is represented as the selected value is still the same:

```
          <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script> 
            function getVat() { // Do an Ajax request to retrieve the product price 
            console.log("getVat before ajax", jQuery('#product_name').val());
            jQuery.ajax({ 
                url: './get/vat/get1.php', 
                method: 'POST', 
                data: {'id' : jQuery('#product_name').val()},
                success: function(response){ 
            // and put the price in text field 
                    var newOption = "<option value=" + response + ">" + response + "</option>";

                    $("#vat").append(newOption);
                    $("#vat").val(response);

                    getPrice();
                    }, 
                error: function (request, status, error) { 
                    alert(request.responseText); 
                    }, 
                });                 
            } 
          </script>
```

Comment: `val()` works with `select` elements too. If it's not working for you then either `#vat` is not in the DOM or there is more than one of them, or `response` is not a valid `value` of an `option` within the `select`

Comment: Just checked it. Thats not the case. The script returns the data `1` which is the second option in the combobox

Comment: If that was true then your code would be working, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/u5fw3bko/. There must be some underlying problem. I would suggest you check the *actual* HTML source that's output from the PHP, and also the `response` value itself.

Comment: I see that the selected value is changed to '1'. But the script still shows `<option value = "0">No VAT</option>`. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the script still shows...'? If the selected value is `1`, then it should show the `option` that has that value. Are you using a plugin to style the select at all?

Comment: When I open the dropdown I can see that the right option is marked. Also when I post the value of the dropdown I get the correct value in the database. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/bp5y4723/9/

Answer (score 1):

You are right `<select>` value will be changed with `$("#vat").val(1)`. However this will not create a new `<option>`. If there would be an `<option value="1">` then this option would have been shown. Since it doesn't exist thus HTML have nothing to show and showing default `<option>` of `<select>`.

You need to create a `<option>` and append it to `<select>`.

Here's jQuery on success:

```
var newOption = `<option value=` + response + `>` + response + `</option>`;

$("#vat").append(newOption);
$("#vat").val(response);
```

Comment: How do I need to implement this in my current code?

Comment: inside your `success` function in jquery.

Comment: With the script I only get a new `<option>` in the dropdown.  The option `<option value = "0">No VAT</option>` is still represented like this is the selected value.

Comment: Don't know what's wrong going on. I tried this so many times, and works for me. Here's a dummy code. `var v = 'xyz'; var a = '<option value=' + v + '>' + v + '</option>';  $('#country').append(a); $('#country').val(v);`  here `country` is select box id like `<select id='country'><option value=''></option></select>`

Comment: See update 3 in my first post. I just get a extra option in the dropdown when I run the script

Comment: Yes `$("#vat").append(newOption);` will add new option to `select` and `$("#vat").val(response);` change the value of `select`. Don't know what you are getting on `response`, just to be on safer side use this `response = response.toString()` before using response.

Comment: I added `response = response.toString()` to the script. The response I get is `2` which is the third option in the dropdown

Comment: `<option value="2">Data 2</option>` is the option thats already in the dropdown. By running the script I get a new option: `<option>2</option>`

Comment: The dropdown stays at: `<option value = "0">No VAT</option>`. But when I click on the dropdown I can see that `<option value="2">Data 2</option>` is marked

Comment: Yep it will add again. In order to save from this you can do `$("#vat").html(newOption);`. This will remove all your older `<option>`

Comment: I didn't get what you are asking. new option is created, but value didnt changed? can you share LINK so that i can see whats going on?